# Select random IDs from a table, using MySQLi

Tags: php, time-limit-exceeded, mysqli

I've created a "simple" function that receives a MySQLi resource and, using a custom `where` query, will fetch random IDs from a provided table.

Some caveats on this:

- No object-style! This needs to be understood by people who only know the old `mysql_*` procedural API;
- No `order by rand()`! It is slow, but very tempting;
- It has to allow me to fetch a fixed number of IDs, or all available IDs;
- It must always return something, even if it is a simple array;
- It is required to allow for a table name to be passed;
- A custom `where` is required, since I need to provide complex queries;
- It doesn't really matter if it is a truly random function: pseudo-random is perfectly fine;
- No prepared statements: this function will be used alongside some prepared statements. Those will give errors like ["Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/614671/2729937);
- The code needs to run on PHP 5.3.29.

---

And here's the code:

```
<?PHP
    function get_random_ids_from_table(&$link, $table, $where = null, $length = -1)
    {
        $ids_r = mysqli_query($link, 'select id from `' . $table . '`' . ($where ? ' where ' . $where : ''));
        if(!$ids_r)
        {
            return array();
        }

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($ids_r);

        if(!$count)
        {
            return array();
        }

        $ids = array();
        if($length < 1 || $length > $count)
        {
            while($id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ids_r))
            {
                $ids[] = $id['id'];
            }
            mysqli_free_result($ids_r);
            shuffle($ids);
        }
        else
        {
            while(count($ids) < $length)
            {
                $offset = mt_rand(0, $count - 1);
                if(!isset($ids[$offset]))
                {
                    mysqli_data_seek($ids_r, $offset);
                    $id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ids_r);
                    $ids[$offset] = $id['id'];
                }
            }
            $ids = array_values($ids);
        }

        mysqli_free_result($ids_r);

        return $ids;
    }
```

This function works perfectly fine as-is, but it has a problem: it's still slow! It takes 500-1400ms when executed 4 times! I've already reduced its execution time from 3s. (Old version, for reference: http://pastebin.com/ASfBfWmg). And this is to select IDs from 500 rows. I'm expecting that the code runs on 2000+ rows.

How can I improve its *horrendous* speed? And which other changes you think that are necessary to make it more readable?

Comment: So where is your script spending it's time?  If it is in query, then have you looked at typical query optimization approaches (i.e. having indexes for fields use in WHERE clause, etc.)?

Comment: @MikeBrant The time is being all spent on the PHP side. The queries themselves are optimized, with primary keys being used. Sadly, the queries are fairly complex, but aren't what is dragging down the code. I'm saying this because the query to fetch the IDs runs in around 30-50ms on MySQL Workbench and PHPMyAdmin. In my opinion, what may be bogging it is the `mysqli_data_seek()`, which may require that all the rows are fetched and kept *somewhere*.

Comment: Why aren't you delegating the randomization to MySQL? Fetching a lot of rows just to throw most of them away is wasteful for CPU, disk and, if on a different machine, network bandwidth.

Comment: @D.Jurcau To be very honest, I've seen alternatives to fetching random rows, but I don't understand how they work. Most of them are nearly incomprehensible to me. That's why I came up with  . . . this thing. One solution I thought about now is to fetch only a few columns `where rand() > 0.5 limit x`, but I don't know how much worse it is than my current code. Also, I need to return **all** IDs, if the number of IDs available is lower than `$length` or `$length == -1`.

Comment: I tend to agree with @D.Jurcau in this case.  What is the **simplest** solution also holds value.  And in this case, a simple `SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() ... LIMIT ? ...` query would greatly simplify your code.  Try it out to see what query times you can expect from the knowingly sub-optimal randomized query.  You might find it is reasonable compared to your current approach.  Your number of rows should not be a problem at all for a randomized query to give "reasonable" performance.

Comment: @MikeBrant I agree that it is faster *now*. But will it still hold it's speed when I run it 4 times with different queries and an ever-increasing number of rows?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Run it 4 times in a row and see. The number of times you run it should not matter assuming you are not running up against resource constraints. The time should scale linearly with number of queries, given fixed table size.  As your tables grow, you can think about more suitable approaches which could range from more performance-optimized randomization queries (lots on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on this) to migrating to a database that better handles this randomization feature. I guess mainly my thought is don't overcomplicate your code of the present for problems of the future.

Comment: @MikeBrant I know it will work fine *now*, but I'm not even worried about *now*. I'm worried about 10 months from now. And no, 10 months from now, the code won't be maintained by me anymore. And my tables grew more than I expected, and the 1st sub-optimal code had to be changed. If there's nothing I can do *now*, I'm fine with that. Also, the number of times counts *a lot*. The DBMS needs to re-order **everything** *n* times. That's the slow part on `SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() ... LIMIT ?`. And `RAND()` itself is slow too.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel How this function is called would obviously be determined by whatever is upstream of this function.  If you call this function `n` times with `n` different where clauses, it will take `0(n)` time to execute regardless of how you get your random sample.  I was speaking just with regards to optimizing this function and how it operates to minimize your function execution time.  If you have opportunities up the call stack to cache results, remove redundant calls to this function, etc. then you could potentially improve on `O(n)`.

Comment: @MikeBrant That function is used in multiple repeating and non-repeating places. On a specific page, it is used 4 times, while on others it is used once. I don't know how to describe how it is used, but the `$where` can contain relationships between 4-5 tables. It's a very intensive function. I can't provide a link to where you can see the code in action. I could try to show an example of how the function works in general.

Comment: @MikeBrant I've tested and running http://pastebin.com/k7uHqysq is around 2-6 times **slower** than my current code. Basically, a straight-forward ``'select id from `' . $table . '`' . ($where ? ' where ' . $where : '') . ' order by rand()' . ($length && $length > 0 ? ' limit ' . $length : '')`` and fetching all that was returned. Strange . . .

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I would actually expect the query to take longer using `rand()` approach.  I would have thought the potential time savings would be in minimizing work in the application.  It is good to test these things :)  Will leave some thoughts in answer below on how to potentially simplify your current code.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments section, we talked about options around the DB queries.  It sounds like `ORDER BY rand()` may not be suitable for your use case in dealing with those execution times (which still seem odd to me given size of dataset).

So let's assume rather than look at optimizing that randomized query (again there are many good examples of this out there), or caching query results locally in some manner that you find appropriate, we are just going to look at simplifying your code, but sticking with the approach of randomizing the id's in the application.

I would suggest that you test through both sides of your if-else conditional to understand the relative completion speed of the "download all ids and shuffle" vs. the "random row retrieval" side of the conditional.  Ask yourself things like:

- Do you really need both sides of this conditional?
- What are the actual use cases of your application?
- Are you primarily going to be grabbing one or a few rows at a time vs. grabbing entire set of id's?

This may influence your way of thinking about this section of code.  It might even, for example, prompt you to split this function with one function being called to get full result set and another function being called to get partial result set.

You may want to look at randomization approach in the data seek side of the conditional.  If you were trying to retrieve a substantial portion of (but not full) result set, you could waste a lot of time in the while loop trying to find an offset that has not already been set in the result array.

A better approach to randomization might be:

```
// generate array of offsets to search by getting
// $length number of random offset keys
// assume $length has already been verified to be <= $count
// not shown - you might check whether sorting $target_offsets helps with access time at all
$target_offsets = array_rand(range(0, $count - 1), $length);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; i++) {
    // seek record and read into $ids array
    mysqli_data_seek($ids_r, $target_offsets[$i]);
    $id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ids_r);
    $ids[] = $id['id'];
}
```

Regardless of approach here, you need to understand if at some percentage of full result set, it might be faster to retrieve full array, shuffle and slice to get the desired result vs. random row retrieval.

A few other thoughts in looking at your code:

- Always strive to use meaningful variables names.

Consider these examples:

```
$ids_r => $id_results
$link => $mysqli_link
$length => $record_limit
```

These immediately give code reader exact understanding of what is stored in the variable.

- You are doing nothing to validate the input to your function.  You shoudd consider validating, for example that a valid mysqli resource, non-zero length string for table name and where clause, and integer value for record limit are passed. Throw exception of fail out quickly if these conditions are not met.
- Your code has no comments. You should always consider appropriate comments to make your code more readable.
- Speaking of more readable code. You should strive to keep your code < 80 chraracters per line.  You only have one questionable example in your code:

Here:

> ```
> $ids_r = mysqli_query($link, 'select id from `' . $table . '`' .
> ($where ? ' where ' . $where : ''));
> ```

which could be made more readable like:

```
$where = $where ? ' WHERE ' . $where : '';
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM `' . $table . '`' . $where;
$id_results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Comment: Won't your alternative method retrieve repeated IDs? Also, `$id_results` is not a good name. `$ids_result` would be a better name, since you're retreaving multiple IDs with a single result. I do agree about `$mysqli_link` and `$record_limit`. I don't validate the input because the input is all done by me. It is guaranteed that the input is withing spec. Always. But a basic canity check might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The means by which `$target_offsets` is defined will not retrieve duplicate offset keys. `array_rand()` will generate an array of `$length` elements.  Each of those elements will be hold a unique key value from the array created from `range()` (where the keys actually match the values). There are other ways to approach this problem as well (like shuffling the array built from `range()` and simply grabbing first `$length` items, so if you are not happy with "randomness" generated by `array_rand()` you can certainly tweak these couple lines of code to an alternate implementation.

Comment: Isn't it better to use a `foreach`, like on here: http://pastebin.com/xZPE8DuE ?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You could just as easily use `forEach()`.  Whether it is "better" or not might depend on who you ask, as there are some who tend to get hung on on some known use cases where `forEach()` does not perform as well as simple loop.  A lot of time the decision may also come down to what sort of scope context you need and whether you need to break from the loop at some point (neither of which should be concern here).

Comment: I can see what you mean. I don't know why but the `foreach` looks cleaner. A lot cleaner.  I will have to try and see which one is "the best" on my system.